# On an approximation to Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

I've been recently reading Yuan Wang's [paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812701190_0008) on an approximation to Goldbach's problem, in which he showed that

**Proposition 1:** For all large even integer $x$, there exists $1<n<x-1$ such that $n(x-n)$ has no prime divisors $\le x^{1/8}$, at most three prime divisors in $x^{1/8}<p\le x^{1/2}$ such that $p^2\nmid n(x-n)$.

From this, he concluded without elaborations that

**Proposition 2:** For all large even integer $x$, there exists $1<n<x-1$ such that $n(x-n)$ has at most five prime factors.

However, the best I can do from proposition 1 is that $n(x-n)$ has at most six prime factors:

Let $q$ be the product of all $m$ prime divisors of $N=n(x-n)$ that are $\le x^{1/2}$. Then

$$
x^{m/8}<q\le x^{m/2}
$$

Moreover

$$
{N\over x^{m/2}}\le\frac Nq<{N\over x^{m/8}}<x^{2-\frac m8}
$$

By definition, we know that all prime divisors of $N/q$ are $>x^{1/2}>(N/q)^{1\over2(2-m/8)}:=(N/q)^{1/s}$. Now, all we need is to find out the number of prime divisors of $N$ based on different values of $m$. For all $1\le m\le3$, wee see that $3<s<4$, so $N/q$ has at most three prime divisors. This indicates that $N$ should only have at most six prime divisors.

This made me confused about roles of $m\le3$ in his paper, so I wonder whether anyone could help me understand this better.

Comment: Is there a difference between prime divisors and prime factors (e.g. does one count multiplicity)?

Comment: It seems you are attacking on Goldbach's problem,but one the wrong way.Hope this conjecture helps. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173510/arithmetic-progression-and-average-of-two-prime-numbers

Comment: @Jacob I edited the answer. The conclusion counts five with multiplicity, but $p|N$ that are in $(x^{1/8},x^{1/2}]$ satisfy $p^2\nmid N$.

Comment: @miket I am not attacking the problem myself but reading someone else's in the 1950s.

Comment: The propositions as worded seem incorrect. Consider $N=n(x-n)=p^5q$ with $N^{1/8}<p,q\leq N^{1/2}$. Then it clearly satisfies proposition 1 but not 2.

Comment: @Jacob Well, $x$ is not the same as $N$, so that’s not a counter example to proposition 2.

Comment: @TravorLZH Oh… that’s what I’ve been missing this entire time. I was very confused since I had been misreading it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n,x-n<x$, there can be at most two prime factors of $N=n(x-n)$ that are $\geq x^{1/2}$ by the pigeonhole principle, as each must divide either $n$ or $x-n$. Assuming $p^2\not\mid N$ for $p\mid N$, $p\leq x^{1/2}$ as you said (I failed to find this in the paper but I did not search thoroughly), we find that there can be at most $5$ prime factors of $N$.